# How to wait for non empty input field in Selenium Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, phantomjs

I'm trying to automatically run the currency converter in https://www.mastercard.us/en-us/consumers/get-support/convert-currency.html using Selenium in Python. Here is what I got so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver                                                                                                                                        
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By                                                                                                                               
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select                                                                                                                      
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait                                                                                                               
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 

link1 = 'https://www.mastercard.us/en-us/consumers/get-support/convert-currency.html'

driver1 = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver1.get(link1)

script = """ var select = arguments[0];
             for(var i = 0; i < select.options.length; i++) {
               if(select.options[i].value == arguments[1]) {
                 select.options[i].selected = true;
               }
             }
         """

driver1.find_element_by_id('getDate').send_keys('05-Sep-2017')                                                                                                        

select = driver1.find_element_by_id('firstID')                                                                                                                        
driver1.execute_script(script, select, 'USD');                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              

driver1.find_element_by_name('txtTAmt').send_keys('1.00')                                                                                                             
driver1.find_element_by_name('txtBankFee').send_keys('0.00')                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                

select = driver1.find_element_by_id('newID')                                                                                                                          
driver1.execute_script(script, select, 'EUR');                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              

driver1.find_element_by_id('btnSubmit').click()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             

wait = WebDriverWait(driver1, 100)                                                                                                                                    
element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,                                                                                                                                  
                     '//*[@name="txtCardAmt" and text() != ""]')))                                                                                          
print(element.text)
```

The problem is that the field "txtCardAmt" never gets populated and I'm getting a timeout exception. My question is, how can I wait for the server to finish the computation?

PS: I know there is easier ways to select options using the `Select` class, however in this website they do not work for some reason.

Comment: You need to use the 'wait.until_not' EC for text_to_be_present_in_element wait.until_not(ExpectedConditions.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.Name,"txtCardAmt"),'existing text'))... This should wait till the existing text disappears. The dropdown is created with a combination of span, ul and li. You will need to manually click and select the option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you wait until the **text** of the element with name **txtCardAmt** is not empty. The problem is that this is always true.

If you take a look to the interested html:

```
<input type="text" name="txtCardAmt" ng-model="mcz.txtCardAmt" 
class="mczreadonly ng-pristine ng-valid mczblue" placeholder="0"
readonly="readonly" disabled="">
```

you can see that the there isn't text.

The info that you are you looking for (not visible in the html) is in the attribute **value**:

[image]

That is **7.38** in my example.

So:

```
elem = driver1.find_element_by_name('txtCardAmt')
value = elem.get_attribute("value")
print(value)
```

Your code regarding the selection of the date and the currencies doesn't work. In my example I used the xpath in order to do that. I'm sure there are better way to do this tasks. I used the xpath returned by the tools of the inspector of my browser.

The entire example:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

link1 = 'https://www.mastercard.us/en-us/consumers/get-support/convert-currency.html'
driver1 = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=r'/pathTo/phantomjs')
driver1.get(link1)

driver1.find_element_by_id('getDate').click()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver1, 20)
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/a[1]/span")))
driver1.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/a[1]/span").click()
driver1.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='transactiondatepicker']/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]/a").click()


#select = driver1.find_element_by_id('firstID')
#driver1.execute_script(script, select, 'USD');
driver1.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='mczRowC']/div[2]/button").click()

wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//*[@id='mczRowC']/div[2]/div/ul/li[146]/a")))
driver1.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='mczRowC']/div[2]/div/ul/li[146]/a").click()


driver1.find_element_by_name('txtTAmt').send_keys('1.00')
driver1.find_element_by_name('txtBankFee').send_keys('2.00')

#select = driver1.find_element_by_id('newID')
#driver1.execute_script(script, select, 'EUR');
driver1.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='mczRowD']/div[2]/button").click()
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//*[@id='mczRowD']/div[2]/div/ul/li[49]/a")))
driver1.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='mczRowD']/div[2]/div/ul/li[49]/a").click()


driver1.find_element_by_id('btnSubmit').click()

time.sleep(3)
elem = driver1.find_element_by_name('txtCardAmt')
value = elem.get_attribute("value")
print(value)
```